# Call C# dll from F#

Tags: c#, dll, f#, interop

Is there a simply way to load and call functions of a C# dll from F# both located in the same solution?

I've set up this very simple example:

- My solution is called **FSharpInterop** and contains two project

  1. One C# library called **CSharpComm** `"CSharpComm\CSharpComm.csproj"`
  2. One F# project called **FSharpInterop** `"FSharpInterop\FSharpInterop.fsproj"`

The C# library provides this simple service:

```
using System;

namespace CSharpComm
{
    public class CSharpService
    {
        public string Request()
        {
            return "Hello World provided by C#";
        }
    }
}
```

### 1st attempt: open command

After adding the C# project in the F# reference (right click on the References icon Add Reference... > Projects > Select CSharpComm), I tried to run this line in F#:

```
open CSharpComm
```

Error message: `InteropHelloWorld.fsx(1,6): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'CSharpComm' is not defined.`

### 2nd attempt: #r command

Tried to run:

```
#r "C:\src\FSharpInterop\CSharpComm\bin\Debug\CSharpComm.dll"
```

or

```
#r "C:\src\FSharpInterop\CSharpComm\bin\Debug\CSharpComm"
```

This ends up with the error message: `Invalid directive. Expected '#r "<file-or-assembly>"'.`

### 3rd attempt: Nuclear option

I've tried using the interop service library:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

module InteropWithNative =
    [<DllImport(@"C:\src\FSharpInterop\CSharpComm\bin\Debug\CSharpComm.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
    extern void Request()
InteropWithNative.Request()
```

Error message: `> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'Request' in DLL 'C:\src\FSharpInterop\CSharpComm\bin\Debug\CSharpComm.dll'. at FSI_0005.InteropWithNative.Request() at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005.main@()`

Here I guess I need to instantiate a `CSharpService` object first but the Interop doesn't let me create a ctor in F#. Also, even if I manage to call the C# service that way, that looks a bit overkill for two technologies that supposes to cohabit easily.

### Last attempt: Stack overflow

Following this question [Import/open DLLs in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63677223/import-open-dlls-in-f), I tried to add an `<ItemGroup>` in my F# project but didn't find where and how I can do that (I thought Visual Studio would take care of that when adding the reference project).

### Additional info on my solution

**F# App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**F# packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FSharp.Core" version="5.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

**[Edit] FSharpInterop.fsproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>425bd4f6-3577-4c20-9ceb-3f95609706d8</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>FSharpInterop</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>FSharpInterop</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <UseStandardResourceNames>true</UseStandardResourceNames>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>false</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(AssemblyName).XML</DocumentationFile>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <Tailcalls>true</Tailcalls>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <WarningLevel>3</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(AssemblyName).XML</DocumentationFile>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(MinimumVisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(FSharpTargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets') ">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="InteropHelloWorld.fsx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core.5.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="CSharpComm">
        <HintPath>..\CSharpComm\bin\Debug\CSharpComm.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Interop is about calling into native code, so that's irrelevant. What's in your `.fsproj` file?

Comment: Add a reference to the C# project from the F# project.

Comment: @user1981 Read the question -- they do that under "1st attempt"

Comment: @canton7 That was my last attempt, I added this reference in the ItemGroup `<Reference Include="CSharpComm"><HintPath>..\CSharpComm\bin\Debug\CSharpComm.dll</HintPath></Reference>`

Comment: Can you please post your *whole* `.fsproj` file

Comment: @canton7 Just added the `.fsproj` at the end of the question.

Comment: Maybe try to update to resonable version of the tooling.

Comment: Add refrence to the csproj and not the dll, at least if it the same solution as you stated. Visual Studio for example has very simple options for this.

Comment: dotnet add reference or inside of visual studio depending on how you like to work

Comment: <ItemGroup>
         <ProjectReference Include = "..\CSharpComm\CSharpComm.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

Comment: @ canton7 that is not a project reference but a reference from a fsharp script.

Comment: @user1981 I mean the text "*After adding the C# project in the F# reference (right click on the References icon Add Reference... > Projects > Select CSharpComm),*"

Comment: For your second attempt (from an fsx script file) it looks like you are referencing the file without escaping the backslashes. You could either replace all the backslashes with double backslashes, replace the backslashes with forwards slashes (I think this works) or instead of surrounding the file path with single quotes, you can surround it with triple quotes (equivalent of c# @ string verbatim prefix).

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: This is my first *ever* attempt at `F#`

> Add a reference to the C# project from the F# project

Unsure why this "doesn't work"  (reference the project, not the dll as @user1981 stated)

C# Library Project in Solution:

```
using System;

namespace SampleLibInCSharp
{
    public class CsharpService
    {
        // a static function to do trivial test....
        public static string Request()
        {
            return "Hello World provided by C#";
        }
    }
}
```

Trivial F# Console App (from VS 2019 template), set as startup app in VS: `Program.fs`

```
open System
open SampleLibInCSharp 

// Define a function to construct a message to print
let from whom =
    sprintf "from %s" whom

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let message = from "F#" // Call the function
    printfn "Hello world %s" message
    let cs = CsharpService.Request()
    printfn  "ola %s" cs
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

---

Run the F# console app:

```
Hello world from F#
ola Hello World provided by C#
```

Note: I *did* see some odd red squiglies denoting some syntax error with the message you posted, but it *seems* more like a VS artifact or bug. Rebuilding and/or running is fine (as above).

As stated, this is a trivial F#/C# test only...

Hth...

Comment: First time I tried this I had to restart VS before Intellisense found the C# lib.